# Sending video from ReactNative app to Python Server via socket

Tags: javascript, python, react-native, sockets, websocket

I am developing an application in RN which sends the video from the front camera.
I tried using WebSockets and SocketIO, but that only helps with text transfer.
Also, I know about WebSocketStream in Js but I just can't find any implementation in python.
Guide me please.

Comment: what do you want to do? uploading a video or live stream?

Comment: Live stream. I am trying to create an application like DroidCam.

Answer (score 1):

Websocket is not suitable for this type of applications. you can use technologies like WebRTC for this this purpose. take a look at these technology and frameworks to see which one fit your needs.

- webRTC: for p2p connection
- kurento: webRTC media server
- hls and live streaming technologies

webRTC is a technology developed by google for real-time P2P communication. You can use webRTC to connect two or more end user together and send Data/Audio/Video. Read following resources for more information.

[webRTC](https://webrtc.org/)

[React Native Implementation](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc)

But its only offer P2P connection for you. If you want to store/modify/broadcast your streams you must use something like [Kurento media server](https://www.kurento.org/).

Comment: Could you add some more details about what exactly is webrtc and what should I search to know more?